# CMFCPropertyGridCtrl Adding text

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm having troubles with inserting text in a CMFCPropertyGridCtrl.
Basically, I insert values with the following code :

```
void GridBuilder::buildGrid() { 
    int cycles = 0, buisnessRules = 0;
    for(vector<cycle *>::iterator it = this->listCycle.begin(); it!= this->listCycle.end(); ++it) {
        buisnessRules = 0;
        cycles++;
        if(!this->mFilter->assertCycleConstraints((*it)->idthread, (*it)->dataStart, (*it)->dateStop, (*it)->name.c_str(), cycles)) {
            continue;
        }

        CString text;
        text.Format(_T("cycle : %S"), (*it)->name.c_str());
        CMFCPropertyGridProperty* parent = new CMFCPropertyGridProperty(text);
        mGrid->AddProperty(parent);

        time_t timestampBegin = (*it)->dataStart / 1000;
        char bufferBegin[256];
        strftime(bufferBegin, sizeof(bufferBegin), "%A %d %B %Y - %X", localtime(&timestampBegin));

        time_t timestampEnd = (*it)->dateStop / 1000;
        char bufferEnd[256];
        strftime(bufferEnd, sizeof(bufferEnd), "%A %d %B %Y - %X", localtime(&timestampBegin));

        text.Format(_T("%d"), (*it)->idthread);     parent->AddSubItem(new CMFCPropertyGridProperty(_T("Thread Id"), text));
        text.Format(_T("%S"), (*it)->name.c_str()); parent->AddSubItem(new CMFCPropertyGridProperty(_T("Name"),      text));
        text.Format(_T("%S:%d"), bufferBegin, (*it)->dataStart % 1000); parent->AddSubItem(new CMFCPropertyGridProperty(_T("DateStart"), text));
        text.Format(_T("%S:%d"), bufferEnd,   (*it)->dateStop  % 1000); parent->AddSubItem(new CMFCPropertyGridProperty(_T("DateStop"),  text));
        parent->Expand(FALSE);

        for(vector<br *>::iterator itBr = (*it)->listBr.begin(); itBr!=(*it)->listBr.end(); ++itBr) {
            buisnessRules++;
            if(!this->mFilter->assertBuisnessRuleConstraints((*itBr)->dateStart, (*itBr)->dateStop, (*itBr)->name.c_str(), buisnessRules)) {
                continue;
            }

            UINT64 executionTime = (*itBr)->dateStop - (*itBr)->dateStart;

            CString text;
            text.Format(_T("%S (%d \u00B5s)"), (*itBr)->name.c_str(), executionTime);

            CMFCPropertyGridProperty* buisnessRule = new CMFCPropertyGridProperty(text);
            parent->AddSubItem(buisnessRule);


            text.Format(_T("%S"), (*itBr)->name.c_str()); buisnessRule->AddSubItem(new CMFCPropertyGridProperty(_T("Name"),      text));
            text.Format(_T("%d \u00B5s"), executionTime); buisnessRule->AddSubItem(new CMFCPropertyGridProperty(_T("Execution time"), text));
            buisnessRule->Expand(FALSE);
        }

    }
}
```

---

This works fine and displays everything as I want them to be.
However, my vectors are usually very big (more than 8 000 elements) and this takes a lot of time to render...

I suspect the CMFCPropertyGridCtrl to redraw the whole tree each time I insert a new element which takes quite some time...

---

My question is the following : 
How can I add text in the CMFCPropertyGridCtrl without it redrawing the whole tree ?
or how can I optimize this code ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I do it:

Before you start adding items to the grid, call `LockWindowUpdate` (inherited from `CWnd` - [MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kc4ez6dk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)), then call `UnlockWindowUpdate` ([MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/101eset9.aspx)) and `Invalidate` when done

```
m_Grid->LockWindowUpdate();

// ... populate grid

m_Grid->UnlockWindowUpdate();
m_Grid->Invalidate();
```

Comment: There is no need to call Invalidate (see the documentation you linked for LockWindowUpdate).

Comment: @WernerHenze yes I know what it says, but I do what I do because it doesn't work otherwise :-) (or at least it didn't when I first wrote it under VS2008). I'll levae it there with these comments so the OP can check.

Comment: Thanks ! This seems to answer my question about redrawing the tree.

Comment: However, though it got faster it's still slow... Any idea on how to make it faster ?

Comment: @KingGreed "faster" possibly needs some more grnular profiling to try to identify *where* there are still bottlenecks. Your code is fairly straightforward though so it may be inherently "slow". I'm assuming your talking about Release build too - any use of iterators in Debug will also be slow.